# New features for shiny issues

Tags: r, shiny

I would like help with two brief questions:

*Context:* The executable code below generates clusters and shows in a table which industries are part of each cluster. In addition, an alert made by confirmSweetAlert is being displayed when running Shiny to show which industry is being excluded from generating the clusters.

*Question1:* When I run Shiny the output table is being generated in addition to the alert. I would like the alert to be shown first, and as soon as the "Confirm" button was pressed, then the output table would be generated.

*Question 2:* In the code there is the reset button, when I press, the slider returns to its default values. However, I would like to reset reactiveVal too, so that the alert appears again.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

function.cl<-function(df,k){


  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.8,-23.8), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.8, -49.8, -49.5, -49.8, -49.8,-49.8,-49.8), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

  # Exclude long-distance industries
  coordinates<-subset(df,select=c("Latitude","Longitude")) 
  d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1]) 
  diag(d)<-1000000 
  min_distance<-as.matrix(apply(d,MARGIN=2,FUN=min))
  limite<-mean(min_distance)+sd(min_distance) 

  search_vec <- function(mat, vec, dim = 1, tol = 1e-7, fun = all)
    which(apply(mat, dim, function(x) fun((x - vec) > tol)))
  ind_exclude<-search_vec(min_distance,limite,fun=any)
  if(is_empty(ind_exclude)==FALSE){
    for (i in 1:dim(as.array(ind_exclude))){
      df<-subset(df,Industries!=ind_exclude[i])}}


  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 


  #Number of clusters
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Location
  location<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    location[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                    weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  location<-cbind(location,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 


  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),location[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential","cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Industries)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage + Potential, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)

  return(list(
    "IND" =  ind_exclude,
    "Data" = data_table_1
  ))
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Clustering "),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      sliderInput("Slider", h3("Number of clusters"),
                  min = 2, max = 6, value = 4),
      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("tabela")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  confirmed_status <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  Modelcl<-reactive(function.cl(df,input$Slider))

  output$ind <- renderTable({
    IND <- ((Modelcl()[[1]]))
  })

  observe({
    if(is_empty(Modelcl()[[1]])==FALSE && isFALSE(confirmed_status())){
      confirmSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        inputId = "myconfirmation",
        btn_labels = c("Confirm", "Not yet"),        
        text = tags$div(h5("The industry below is being excluded from clustering:"), 
                        paste(Modelcl()[[1]], collapse = ", ")),
        type="info"
      )
    }})

  observeEvent(input$myconfirmation, {
    if (isFALSE(input$myconfirmation)) {
      confirmed_status(TRUE)
    } 
  })

  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    data_table_1 <- req(Modelcl())[[2]]
    x <- datatable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)],
                   options = list(
                     paging =TRUE,
                     pageLength =  5
                   )
    )
    return(x)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateRadioButtons(session,"Slider", selected = 4)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi shiyn lets you do this quite easily just add a `req(confirmed_status())` statement in your `renderDataTable` and you can reset the reactiveValue at the same time as you reset the other values with `confirmed_status(FALSE)`.

```
output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    req(confirmed_status())
    data_table_1 <- req(Modelcl())[[2]]
    x <- datatable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)],
                   options = list(
                     paging =TRUE,
                     pageLength =  5
                   )
    )
    return(x)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateRadioButtons(session,"Slider", selected = 4)
    confirmed_status(FALSE)
  })
```

Comment: Hello Bertil Baron, any idea for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092033/issue-involving-map-generation-in-shiny