# Issue involving map generation in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Friends could help me resolve the following issue:

I am inserting three executable codes below, the first generates a map using `sftnetworks` package, showing the route between two locations. In this case, the two locations to generate the map were defined:  `from = c(df_spec_clust[1, c("Longitude")], df_spec_clust[1, c("Latitude")])`
and `to = c (df_spec_prop [4, c ("Longitude")], df_spec_prop [4, c ("Latitude")])]`. In the second, I would like to generate the map in Shiny format, but without defining the locations exactly as I did in the first code. I would like them to be selected from the filters I created (Filter 1 and Filter 2). However, I am unable to generate the map. Could you help me ? To show you I managed to generate the map correctly in the third code for the problem in question but using another package (`leaflet`). However, I still couldn't think of a way to make it work using the `sfnetworks` package. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

#### First code

```
library(sf)
library(sfnetworks)
library(tmap)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)

#for the roads file
download.file("https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/raw/master/Test.zip", "Test.zip")
unzip("Test.zip")

#database df
df <- structure(
  list(Property = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Latitude = c(-24.779225, -24.789635, -24.763461, -24.794394, -24.747102,-24.781307,-24.761081),
    Longitude = c(-49.934816, -49.922324, -49.911616, -49.906262, -49.890796,-49.8875254,-49.8875254), 
    Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

#clusters
coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
k=3
clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
df$cluster <- clusters 

#Create database df1
center<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
for(i in 1:k){
  center[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                     weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
center<-cbind(center,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 
df1<-as.data.frame(center)
colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")

#specific cluster and specific property
df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster,]
df_spec_prop<-df[df$Property,]

#create map
roads = st_read("Test/regionbrazil.shp", quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# build sfnetwork
net = as_sfnetwork(roads, directed = FALSE) %>%
  activate("edges") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(weight = edge_length())

# routing
from = c(df_spec_clust[1, c("Longitude")], df_spec_clust[1, c("Latitude")])
to = c(df_spec_prop[4, c("Longitude")], df_spec_prop[4, c("Latitude")])
p1 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = from[1], y = from[2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(net))
p2 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = to[1], y = to[2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(net))
r = tidygraph::convert(net, to_spatial_shortest_paths, p1, p2)

# Extract the bbox for r 
bbox_r = st_as_sfc(r %>% activate(edges) %>% st_bbox())


# filter the net
small_net = st_filter(net, bbox_r)

# plot
plot1<-tm_shape(small_net %>% activate(edges) %>% st_as_sf()) +
  tm_lines() + 
  tm_shape(rbind(p1, p2)) + 
  tm_dots(col = "red", size = 0.5) + 
  tm_shape(r %>% activate(edges) %>% st_as_sf()) + 
  tm_lines(col = "red", lwd = 3)
plot1
```

#### Map generated by the code above

[image: ![image|514x500](upload://bzu1ZmK6GYpD6L0GVkyUI1RYN3M.png)]

#### Second code

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(sf)
library(tidygraph)
library(sfnetworks)
library(tmap)

#for the roads file
 download.file("https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/raw/master/Test.zip", "Test.zip")
 unzip("Test.zip")

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){
  
  #database df
  df <- structure(
    list(Property = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Latitude = c(-24.779225, -24.789635, -24.763461, -24.794394, -24.747102,-24.781307,-24.761081),
         Longitude = c(-49.934816, -49.922324, -49.911616, -49.906262, -49.890796,-49.8875254,-49.8875254), 
         Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #Create database df1
  center<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                  weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center<-cbind(center,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 
  df1<-as.data.frame(center)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
 
  # specific cluster and specific property
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster==Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Property==Filter2,]
  
 
  #create map
 
  roads = st_read("Test/regionbrazil.shp", quiet = TRUE) %>% 
    st_cast("LINESTRING")
  
  # build sfnetwork
  net = as_sfnetwork(roads, directed = FALSE) %>%
    activate("edges") %>%
    dplyr::mutate(weight = edge_length())
  
  # routing
  from = c(df_spec_clust[1, c("Longitude")], df_spec_clust[1, c("Latitude")])
  to = c(df_spec_prop[4, c("Longitude")], df_spec_prop[4, c("Latitude")])
  p1 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = from[1], y = from[2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(net))
  p2 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = to[1], y = to[2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(net))
  r = tidygraph::convert(net, to_spatial_shortest_paths, p1, p2)
  
  # Extract the bbox for r 
  bbox_r = st_as_sfc(r %>% activate(edges) %>% st_bbox())
  
  
  # filter the net
  small_net = st_filter(net, bbox_r)
  
  # plot
  plot1<-tm_shape(small_net %>% activate(edges) %>% st_as_sf()) +
    tm_lines() + 
    tm_shape(rbind(p1, p2)) + 
    tm_dots(col = "red", size = 0.5) + 
    tm_shape(r %>% activate(edges) %>% st_as_sf()) + 
    tm_lines(col = "red", lwd = 3)

  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" =  df
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
          tabPanel("",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                           min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
               selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster"),""),
               selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property"),""),
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Map", plotOutput("Map1"))))
           ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })
  

  output$Map1 <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$Filter1,{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Property)))
  }) 
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Map generated but using leaflet package (It works)

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(tidygraph)

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){
  
  #database df
  df <- structure(
    list(Property = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Latitude = c(-24.779225, -24.789635, -24.763461, -24.794394, -24.747102,-24.781307,-24.761081),
         Longitude = c(-49.934816, -49.922324, -49.911616, -49.906262, -49.890796,-49.8875254,-49.8875254), 
         Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #Create database df1
  center<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                  weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center<-cbind(center,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 
  df1<-as.data.frame(center)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
  
  #specify cluster and specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster==Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Property==Filter2,]
  
  
  #color for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)
  
  # create icon for map
  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$cluster,
                     
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 30, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"
  
# create map
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon = 'ios-close',
      iconColor = 'black',
      library = 'ion',
      markerColor =  clust_colors)
    
  m1<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(leaflet(df_spec_prop) %>% addTiles(), lat=~df_spec_prop$Latitude, lng = ~df_spec_prop$Longitude, icon= icons,label=~cluster)

  for(i in 1:nrow(df_spec_clust)){
    df_line <- rbind(df_spec_prop[,c("Latitude","Longitude")],
                     df_spec_clust[i,c("Latitude","Longitude")])
    m1 <- m1 %>%
      addPolylines(data = df_line,
                   lat=~Latitude,
                   lng = ~Longitude,
                   color="red")
  }
  plot1<-m1} else plot1 <- NULL

  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data"= df
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property"),""),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Map", uiOutput("Map1"))))
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })
  
  output$Map1 <- renderUI({ 
    if(input$Filter1!="") 
      leafletOutput("Leaf1",width = "95%", height = "600") })

  output$Leaf1 <- renderLeaflet({
    req(Modelcl())[[1]]
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$Filter1,{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Property)))
  }) 
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a problem in `selectInput`. You were calling a function to get the `Filter1` and `Filter2`, but the function needs `Filter1` and `Filter2` to execute. The following code executes, but it is slow in showing the map. Updating `Filter1` and `Filter2` gives an updated map, but it takes a few seconds.
A more robust way to define it would be to define the dataframe in a separate function. That will help us define `Filter1` and `Filter2`, and then we can pass on this information to the plot function. This will eliminate the chances of passing non-existing combinations which has been a problem sometimes.

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(sf)
library(tidygraph)
library(sfnetworks)
library(tmap)

###for the roads file
download.file("https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/raw/master/Test.zip", "Test.zip")
unzip("Test.zip")

#database df
df <- structure(
  list(Property = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Latitude = c(-24.779225, -24.789635, -24.763461, -24.794394, -24.747102,-24.781307,-24.761081),
       Longitude = c(-49.934816, -49.922324, -49.911616, -49.906262, -49.890796,-49.8875254,-49.8875254),
       Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

fun.clusters <- function(df,k){
  ## clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k)
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))
  df$cluster <- clusters
  return(df)
}

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){
  ## clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k)
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))
  df$cluster <- clusters
  ##  Create database df1
  center<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                  weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters
  center<-cbind(center,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  df1<-as.data.frame(center)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")

  # specific cluster and specific property
  if (is.null(Filter1)) {
    df_spec_clust <- unique(df1$cluster)
  }else { df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster==Filter1,]}
  if (is.null(Filter1)) {
    df_spec_prop <- unique(df$Property)
  }else {df_spec_prop<-df[df$Property==Filter2,] }


  #create map

  roads = st_read("Test/regionbrazil.shp", quiet = TRUE) %>%
    st_cast("LINESTRING")

  # build sfnetwork
  net = as_sfnetwork(roads, directed = FALSE) %>%
    activate("edges") %>%
    dplyr::mutate(weight = edge_length())

  # routing
  from = c(df_spec_clust[1, c("Longitude")], df_spec_clust[1, c("Latitude")])
  to = c(df_spec_prop[1, c("Longitude")], df_spec_prop[1, c("Latitude")])
  p1 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = from[1], y = from[2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(net))
  p2 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x = to[1], y = to[2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = st_crs(net))
  r = tidygraph::convert(net, to_spatial_shortest_paths, p1, p2)

  # Extract the bbox for r
  bbox_r = st_as_sfc(r %>% activate(edges) %>% st_bbox())


  # filter the net
  small_net = st_filter(net, bbox_r)

  # plot
  plot1<-tm_shape(small_net %>% activate(edges) %>% st_as_sf()) +
    tm_lines() +
    tm_shape(rbind(p1, p2)) +
    tm_dots(col = "red", size = 0.5) +
    tm_shape(r %>% activate(edges) %>% st_as_sf()) +
    tm_lines(col = "red", lwd = 3)

  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" =  df
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl",
             tabPanel("",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 2),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster"),
                                      choices=c(), selected=NULL),
                                      #choices=unique(df$cluster), selected=1),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property"),
                                      choices=c(), selected=NULL)
                                      #choices=df$Property, selected=1)
                          
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Map", plotOutput("Map1"))
                            )
                        )
                      )

             )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dfa <- reactive({
    req(input$Slider)
    fun.clusters(df,input$Slider)
  })
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {

    #abc <- Modelcl()[[2]]
    abc <- dfa()
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Filter1,{
    
    #abcd <- Modelcl()[[2]] %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    abcd <- dfa() %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abcd$Property)))
  })

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    req(input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })

  output$Map1 <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. However I noticed some problems when I was testing, when I inserted cluster 1 property 2, for example, it gave the following error: ```! AnyNA (x) is not TRUE```. But it happens with other combinations too. Would you know why?

Comment: That is because all clusters do not exist for each property. So, you could select cluster_property 3, and cluster to be 1. However, cluster 1 may only be present in property 1, 2 or 4.  One way to resolve this issue is to define the second selectinput for Filter2 on the server side, and define it only after Filter1 is selected. That way you can ensure that non-existing combintions are not picked.

Comment: Thanks!! Could you insert this option that you commented in the reply for me to test? Thanks again YBS

Comment: Hello YBS, sorry for the inconvenience, i would just like to know if you had read my previous question ?? If you can’t do it, no problem, you’ve helped me a lot so far, and I’ll agree with your answer.

Comment: Friend, just a quick question, which now that I remembered to ask: in the case of your answer to ```database df``` and the commands for ```clusters``` are out of ```function.cl```. For the first ```clusters``` commands you entered ```k = 3``` but then in the ```function.cl``` is  ```k```. I was a little confused by this because having the clusters commands twice. The value of ```k``` refers to the value the Slider is in, so wouldn't it just leave the ```clusters``` commands of ```function.cl```? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late delay, I'll check. Thanks YBS